# How to automate AppCenter uploads from Android Studio or Gitlab Pipeline?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know that iOS can use fastlane to automate uploads to AppCenter, but I was wondering if there was anyway to do this from Android Studio or from the Gitlab Pipeline? I'm not finding anything online and it's getting a bit annoying having to upload 4 builds everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastlane can be used for both iOS and android. You can run fastlane action to upload the App in your Gitlab pipeline.
You can also activate the upload on each push or during merging into the master / main branch (or whatever you want).

This is a [plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter) for fastlane made by microsoft for everything around the App Center.

If you have never used fastlane, start with this -> [getting-started/android/setup/](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/)

Another option is to use gradlew and write your own script.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know fastlane was for Android as well.